# Calling CLR stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invoking CLR stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641833/invoking-clr-stored-procedures)

Does anybody know how to call a CLR stored procedure using select statement?

Comment: have a look at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641833/1731716 

hope this will help you!

Comment: You don't `SELECT` from a stored procedure - T-SQL or CLR; stored procedure are meant to be **executed** using `EXEC` or `sp_execute` ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible without `OPENQUERY` or `OPENROWSET`, you'd better use CLR table function.
If you need to insert data from stored procedure

```
insert into Table
exec <your CLR procedure>
```

Comment: The SP accepts 2 parameters and inserts some values into a table. When I excute, it is returning 0 and not inserting into table. So pls let me know how to call it.

Comment: well your table schema should be exactly the same that schema of rowset returned by stored procedure. you can pass parameters into procedure by
`exec <your CLR procedure>
    <parameter1> = value
`